# Cloud Workflows Storage Connector can't access objects in subdirectories

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm using Google Cloud workflows and I want to control what happens next based on the presence or absence of a file in Google Cloud Storage.

I can successfully use the Cloud Storage Connector for Workflows to retrieve the metadata for objects that are sitting in the root directory of a bucket, but when I try to retrive one from any level of directory below the top level, I get a 404 error.

Note, I understand that strictly buckets don't have directories, and that what we see as a file path is really just part of the name of the object, but it seems like the easiest way to describe my problem.

Example code below:

This works as expected:

```
# target object is gs://bucket-name/test_file.txt
main:
  steps:
    - file_init:
        assign:
          - bucket: bucket-name
          - object: test_file.txt
    - fetch_file_details:
        call: googleapis.storage.v1.objects.get
        args:
            bucket: ${bucket}
            object: ${object}
        result: getResult
    - out:
        return: ${getResult}
```

However this does not (and the destination file is *definitely* where it should be):

```
# target object is gs://bucket-name/folder/test_file.txt
main:
  steps:
    - file_init:
        assign:
          - bucket: bucket-name
          - object: folder/test_file.txt
    - fetch_file_details:
        call: googleapis.storage.v1.objects.get
        args:
            bucket: ${bucket}
            object: ${object}
        result: getResult
    - out:
        return: ${getResult}
```

I'm assuming there is some subtle syntax issue with the object name, but I have tried a number of different combinations and nothing seems to be working. I have tried with single quotes, double quotes, CRLF, LF etc. All the usual culprits but nothing has made it work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you trying this path folder/ instead of complete path as mentioned in [this document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/folders#tools) or you can try using [delimiter](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/reference-headers#delimiter). You can refer [this article](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.12/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/gcs_list_operator/index.html#airflow.contrib.operators.gcs_list_operator.GoogleCloudStorageListOperator)

for reference.

Answer (score 1):

I think this builds on some of the content in one of the links that Roopa M provided, but the trick is that the '/' in the object path needed to be encoded as '%2F'

So the following now works:

```
# target object is gs://bucket-name/folder/test_file.txt
main:
  steps:
    - file_init:
        assign:
          - bucket: bucket-name
          - object: folder%2Ftest_file.txt
    - fetch_file_details:
        call: googleapis.storage.v1.objects.get
        args:
            bucket: ${bucket}
            object: ${object}
        result: getResult
    - out:
        return: ${getResult}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another possible solution. If you don't want to add the encoding to your URL, you can use the `text.url_encode` ([doc reference](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/stdlib/text/url_encode)) function in your object param.

```
# target object is gs://bucket-name/folder/test_file.txt
main:
  steps:
    - file_init:
        assign:
          - bucket: bucket-name
          - object: folder%2Ftest_file.txt
    - fetch_file_details:
        call: googleapis.storage.v1.objects.get
        args:
            bucket: ${bucket}
            object: ${text.url_encode(object)}
        result: getResult
    - out:
        return: ${getResult}
```