# GCP Storage Connector get blob

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to get an object from Google Cloud Worfklow by using the Storage connector.
The object path is `bucket_name/folder/object_name.csv`.

My yaml look something like this:

```
...
// initialize variables and stuff

            steps:
                - get_urls:
                        call: googleapis.storage.v1.objects.get
                        args:
                            bucket: "bucket_name"
                            object: "/folder/object_name.csv"
                        result: csv_url

...
```

When iI run the code it raise a 404 error even though the file exists. The thing is when I put the object in this path: `bucket_name/object_name.csv`, the code works and return the file.

I also tried to encode the url as the doc [suggest](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/googleapis/storage/v1/objects/get) but with no success.

Does anybody has any idea how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you try to remove the leading / in your object definition?

Comment: Sorry for the delay; I tried to remove the leading "/" but it didn't solve the problem; i found the solution by replacing each "/" with "%2F"!

Comment: My bad. I knew it and I mentioned it to the engineering team. Therefore, they implemented a url_encode function to simplify the use: https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/stdlib/text/url_encode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77320214/16483772)) that if a blob is inside a subdirectory, you need to encode the `/` character as `%2F`, otherwise you'll get a `404 NOT FOUND` error.

Answer (score 1):

You can

1. Remove leading slash https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/request-endpoints#encoding
2. Verify IAM permission to the bucket
3. If the issue persists, check the Cloud Storage logs for more information on the error

Here's the suggested YAML content:

```
      steps:
    - get_object:
        call: googleapis.storage.v1.objects.get
        args:
          bucket: bucket_name
          object: folder/object_name.csv
        result: object_contents
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i found out that, if your file is in a subdirectory, you need to encode the "/" as "%2F"!

Answer (score 1):

Following the suggestion from [@guillaume blaquiere](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11372593/guillaume-blaquiere)'s comment, I added the following answer to a similar questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77564943/7366911

If you don't want to use the `%2F`, instead you can use the `text.url_encode` function in your object param ([doc reference](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/stdlib/text/url_encode)).